# sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk, what are these four numbers? Will they change?

Tags: linux, disk, dmesg, scsi

I can usually see this log in dmesg:

```
sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Can you please explain what are these 4 numbers?

Will these numbers change after reboot? or it should be constant?

Comment: And you didn't ask, but: the way to get unchanging access to a disk is not to rely on `/dev/sda` or any of these numbers, but instead use the `/dev/disk/by-*` symlinks that are provided by `udev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The four numbers represent a [SCSI address](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/scsiaddr.html), often referred to as H:C:T:L. The four components are host, channel (or bus), target, and LUN.

With drives you’re likely to encounter on an end-user system (SATA, consumer NVMe, USB), the channel, target, and LUN will all be zero. The host number will depend on which port the drive is connected to, and how it’s enumerated; for fixed drives (SATA, NVMe), it won’t vary most of the time, but it’s not impossible for it to change.

Comment: Especially if you're using PCIe SATA cards; adding another card may change the order of disovery on reboot, and so change the numbers.